# create function in line with () => func

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

I want to create an easy function as a parameter in unity, something like this (in c#):

```
Invoke((() => { alarm = true; }), 3 );
```

but this is not working in unity, it says: you cannot convert lambda expressions into strings because invoke needs a string. Any solution?

Comment: For an alternate, possibly cleaner solution (without reflection), you could:`IEnumerator SetAlarm() { yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f); alarm = true; }` and run it with `StartCoroutine(SetAlarm())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading about it, `Invoke` takes a `string` and `float`. It probably uses reflection underneath, so it wants a string name of a method to call later. This would mean that you cannot pass a delegate or lambda, but have to use a named method:

```
Invoke("SetAlarm", 3);

...

void SetAlarm() {
   alarm = true;
}
```

See:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30297/invoke-method-whats-the-real-use.html
- https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/invoke